# Moving DNS management from Office 365 to my own host

Tags: domain-name-system, microsoft-office-365, ns-record

At the moment the DNS for our domain is managed at Office 365. This means the NS records point to Microsoft (`dig -t ns ourdomain.com`):

1. `ns1.bdm.microsoftonline.com`
2. `ns2.bdm.microsoftonline.com`
3. `ns3.bdm.microsoftonline.com`
4. `ns4.bdm.microsoftonline.com`

Because we will be migrating to G Suite, I would like to change this to our (former) domain provider. 
Does this mean I have to add the NS records in Office 365 pointing to the other provider? The problem is, I cannot find these settings anywhere in the control panel. There is only the possibility to add `MX`, `CNAME`, `TXT` and `A` records

If I look at the DNS records at the former provider, there is no record pointing to Office/Microsoft. NS records at the former provider look like this:

1. `ns1.exsilia.net.`
2. `ns2.exsilia.net.`

Where should I change the settings so that the DNS can be managed at our former provider Exsilia?

Comment: You need to check the registrar for your domain, which may not necessarily be where your web hosting is done.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the roles of a registrar and nameserver, and yes they can be the same.

The registrar,  is the company that you purchase a domain,  register it with ICANN, and manages your NS, DS, and Glue records with upstream nameservers.

Many registrars offer nameservers as an included service.

Your nameservers simply answer dns requests. These are the two providers you mention.

If you are looking to switch to Google apps, I'd highly recommend transferring your domain to Google domains,  it's an excellent service and not bad on the bank, in the process they will attempt to transfer your zone from Microsoft. This zone file is never complete,  you should always backup and transfer the data in your zone file first.

Also,  Google apps actually allows you to deliver email to both gsuite, office 365, and any number of additional destinations with their **dual delivery**.  this way you can update your mx records before migrating users and make migration easier.

Good Luck

[Dual Delivery Blog Post](https://www.jacobdevans.com/dual-delivery-dual-cloud-office-365-and-google-apps-and-and-and-and/)

[Configuration Guide](https://support.google.com/a/answer/96855?hl=en)

Comment: **only glue** records is a job of pure registrar in real world

Comment: really? how do the NS and DS records go up.

Comment: OK, I forgot about RFC 3658, mea culpa (I'm not a hostmaster more than a decade), but management of **zone for delegated domain** isn't task of registrar anyway, isn't it?